# Exposing a C++ API to Python

Tags: c++, python, boost, swig

I'm currently working on a project were I had to wrap the C++ classes with Python to be able to script the program. So my specific experience also involved embedding the Python interpreter in our program.

The alternatives I tried were:

- Boost.Python

  I liked the cleaner API produced by Boost.Python, but the fact that it would have required that users install an additional dependency made us switch to SWIG.
- SWIG

  SWIG's main advantage for us was that it doesn't require end users to install it to use the final program.

What have you used to do this, and what has been your experience with it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've used both (for the same project): Boost is better integrated with the STL, and especially C++ exceptions.  Also, its memory management mechanism (which tries to bridge C++ memory management and Python GC) is way more flexible than SWIG's.  However, SWIG has *much* better documentation, no external dependencies, and if you get the library wrapped in SWIG for Python you're more than half-way there to getting a Java/Perl/Ruby wrapper as well.

I don't think there's a clear-cut choice: for smaller projects, I'd go with Boost.Python again, for larger long-lived projects, the extra investment in SWIG is worth it.

Answer (score 18):

EDIT - the Robin project is sadly abandoned, and won't be much use today

I've used [Robin](http://code.google.com/p/robin/) with great success.

**Great** integration with C++ types, and creates a single .cpp file to compile and include in your shared object.

Comment: +1 never heard of this before and it actually looks quite good.

Comment: Link seems broken. Here's one that works: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Robin/1.0.1

Comment: Thanks Jason, the updated project link is http://code.google.com/p/robin/ (version 1.0.4 is out), edited the answer.

Comment: In 2017: although this answer has received 18 upvotes, this project seems to be stuck in abandoned Google Code repo, and it remains uncertain if it has been revived elsewhere.

Comment: @LennartRolland - fair enough, the last release is from 2009 and is probably unusable today

Answer (score 7):

I suggest [SIP](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/sip/intro). SIP is better than SWIG due to the following reasons:

1. For a given set of files, swig generates more duplicate (overhead) code than SIP. SIP manages to generate less duplicate (overhead) code by using a library file which can be statically or dynamically linked. In other words SIP has better scalability.
2. Execution time of SIP is much less than that of SWIG. Refer [Python Wrapper Tools: A Performance Study](http://people.web.psi.ch/geus/talks/europython2004_geus.pdf). Unfortunately link appears broken. I have a personal copy which can be shared on request.

Comment: I'm interested in seeing it. Can you post it somewhere and link to it? Otherwise we can arrange for you to send it directly to me.

Comment: The wayback machine has a copy: http://web.archive.org/web/20070703071726/http://people.web.psi.ch/geus/talks/europython2004_geus.pdf

Comment: I don't think the benchmark is meaningful for SWIG. The author doesn't use the -builtin or -O flag for SWIG, both of which dramatically improve performance.

Answer (score 5):

[pyrex](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python/Pyrex/) or [cython](http://cython.org/) are also good and easy ways for mixing the two worlds.

Wrapping C++ using these tools is a bit trickier then wrapping C but it can be done. [Here](http://wiki.cython.org/WrappingCPlusPlus) is the wiki page about it.

Answer (score 2):

A big plus for Boost::Python is that it allows for tab completion in the ipython shell: You import a C++ class, exposed by Boost directly, or you subclass it, and from then on, it really behaves like a pure Python class.

The downside: It takes so long to install and use Boost that all the  Tab-completion time-saving won't ever amortize ;-(

So I prefer Swig: No bells and whistles, but works reliably after a short introductory example.