# How to pass two python dictionaries to C++ function received by map

Tags: c++, python

I want to call a C++ function in Python that takes two Python dictionaries whose key values are lists, as parameters, like:

```
a = {'str1': [1, 2, 3], 'str2': [4, 5, 6]}
b = {'str3': [7, 8, 9], 'str4': [10, 11, 12]}
cppFunction(a, b)
```

And in C++, the function called take the two dictionaries and store them in two variables of the type `map<string, vector<int>>`. How can I do this? Do I have to use boost library?

Thanks,

Qingkun

Comment: How are you planning to wrap your C++ function? Boost? SWIG? Shiboken? .. or writing the wrapper yourself? .. We need to know that before we can answer that question. If you don't know yet, please clarify that you're asking what wrapping method/library is best/easiest for your case.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams @Macke    I'm trying to use the lists indexed by the strings in my C++ function, like do some calculations. I have no idea of which way can be most efficient in terms of running speed. Because I'm kinda new to these, I'll appreciate it if you could introduce a simple and efficient way to go. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As I understand there are two parts to your question: 1. How to call a C++ function from python?, 2. What data structures should be used in C++ for holding the inputs for the computation?

An answer to 1. is a long story. See, for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076300/extending-python-with-c-c) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276761/exposing-a-c-api-to-python). For 2., for the given example, I would either use `map<string, vector<int>>`, as you have suggested, within a wrapper class, or `multimap<string, int>` which would be quicker to use as its existing interface is likely to be useful more readily.

**Update**: Added link to an another answer for 1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I know how to call C++ function from python, but I only know that with values or single variables as parameters, by calling PyArg_ParseTuple() in C++ function to get the arguments. However, now I want dictionaries with lists as key values to be the passing parameter. How can I do this? It will be better if you could give me some sample code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass Python arguments to a C/C++ function that don't have direct C/C++ equivalents (i.e. aren't strings or numbers), the best you can do is get pointers to them as generic Python objects and treat them as such.

This means your C++ extension code will have to deal with them in generic terms just like the Python interpreter does, which entails doing things like looking up their methods and calling them to manipulate -- as in retrieve, set, or delete -- their contents if they're container objects, such as `lists`, `dicts`, and the like. Your extension can then use this information to build the specific C++ `map<>` template type you want.

The open source [PyCXX](http://cxx.sourceforge.net/PyCXX.html) project provides facilities to make it easier to write C++ Python extensions in general, as well as providing pre-written C++ classes for handling `Dict` and `List` arguments. Better yet, you can treat them as abstract `Sequence` and `Mapping` objects which will make your extension code able to handle other Python types that implement the same interfaces.