# Calling a C++ Functions through a Python Script

Tags: c++, python, qt, boost-python, word-wrap

I have a scenario where I have some functions in C++ classes and I want to be able to call them using a python script. Let's say I have a function

```
void greet(_msg);
    std::cout >> _msg >> std::endl;
```

I want to be able to call it trough a custom Python call and pass arguments to it, for example using

```
saySomething("Hello")
```

As a .py file I want it to call the greet function and pass "Hello" as an argument.

I know it's a subject that has been throughly discussed, and I've done a share of research on embedding python in C++, I've managed to read values from a python script using the standard Python/C API and run a function in Python from C++ and pass argument to it, but I can't seem to get my head around how to achieve this specific outcome.

I've had a look at ctypes and various wrappin libraries such as boost:python or swig, but I can't seem to understand to which degree they could help me achieve want I want.

Comment: "run a function in Python from C++" what do you mean with that ? If you like to mask C/C++ as Python API you can apply the basic rules of the Python bindings for C/C++, there is also the boost::python library that can be easier to handle when writing python API starting from C++ code.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear - What I want is being able to have a python script that calls a specific function of a C++ class being able to pass arguments to it.

More or less like a GUI, but done through python scripts instead of buttons.

Comment: so you are looking for this http://docs.python.org/3.2/extending/extending.html , or boost::python ( probably easier ), and also the answers to this question can be a good starting point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276761/exposing-a-c-api-to-python . Anyway, you want to generate python api for C++ code, that's it, just follow the official guide or use this libs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on which version of Python you are interested in, 2.x or 3.x,
read through the **Extending and Embedding the Python Interpreter** chapter for [2.x](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/) or [3.x](http://docs.python.org/3/extending/). You are interested only in **extending** Python, so section the **1. Extending Python with C or C++** will provide you with complete explanation how to implement what you need in order to be able to call your functions implemented in C++ from Python script.

Certainly, there are numerous libraries and generators which allow you to wrap C/C++ APIs for Python (e.g. [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/libs/python/) or [SWIG](http://swig.org/)), but your case sounds simple enough, that for the purpose of learning it is IMO better to get familiar with Python C API. Even if you use these tools, you will frequently have to get down to Python C API anyway or at least understand it.

Answer (score 4):

I recently needed to do this very thing. Boost.Python does what we're looking for (and more) but personally (as much as I love Boost) I find it a little overkill to have to drag in half the Boost library to get one feature. SWIG also wasn't really an option for me as code generation always becomes a pain to maintain while class structures change (Don't get me wrong, these are BRILLIANT solutions!, just not what I was looking for).

So, the only thing left for me was to implement it from first principles (Python/C API). Hense, "ECS:Python" was born. ECS:Python (Embedded C++ Scripting with Python) is a simple C++ Python wrapper library I designed specifically for C++ developers. It allows you to expose objects from a C++ application to an embedded Python interpreter for interactive scripting, and it's very light-weight and easy to use.

Its free (BSD) and open source. If you're interested here it is:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/ecspython

Answer (score 3):

You can use the weave.inline() function, which is part of the scipy package, to compile and execute C/C++ files and get their output from within your python script.